# Prank Tag? It Must Be A Joke

Tags: discussion, tags, interesting-tags

Is [flying saucer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags/flying-saucer/info) real? If not, what should we do about it?

Comment: If not I would say get rid of the tag, but seeing the names people are giving to software these days I wouldn't rule it out being real when you can have a phone with an OS version of Kitkat or Ice Cream Sandwich.

Comment: LOL! Where you been all this time Adrian?

Comment: The [excerpt history](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/95475/revisions) will show you who created a tag description. I created it as a tag as it is often useful for people to know what renders a VF page to PDF. It forms the basis of lots of questions in that area.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Its real. see https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer